# JSX Function doesn't show return

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

As the title says, I can not figure out why the return of a function doesn't show on screen.
The object **words.First.wordsdata** is holding key-value pairs

```
import React from "react";

const WordList = ({ words }) => {
    return (
    <div>
        { words && 
            Object.entries(words.First.wordsdata).forEach(([key, value]) => {
              return(<div>{key} - {value}</div>);
            })
        }
    </div>
  );
};

export default WordList;
```

If I change the return to log it out, then
this one does show everything correctly in dev tools

```
return(console.log(key, value));
```

To give a full view, this is the file that calls the component

```
class Words extends Component {
  render() {
    //console.log(this.props)
    const { words, auth } = this.props;
    if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to="/" />;
    return (
      <div>
        <WordList words={words} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried changing the return to simple HTML and It still doesn't show anything

Comment: `.forEach` should be `.map`

Comment: Use ***map*** instead of ***forEach***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers, indeed changing `.forEach` to  `.map` did the trick.